# Maven project fails to find Groovy class

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I have a very simple maven project
pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>TestMaven</groupId>
<artifactId>TestMaven</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have two classes in src/main/java:

MyClass.groovy:

```
class MyClass {
   public static String getAlex()
   {
      return "alex"
   }
}
```

And ParentClass.java:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public ParentClass()
    {

    }
   public String getStuff()
   {
      String alex = MyClass.getAlex();
      return "alex";
   }
}
```

And here are my maven details:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T16:58:10-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_17, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

When I go to do `mvn clean install`

I get hit with this esoteric error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project TestMaven: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/afrieden/Projects/TestMaven/src/main/java/ParentClass.java:[15,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable MyClass
[ERROR] location: class ParentClass
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

What does this error mean?  Why is this happening?  This should be a hello world of maven projects.

Comment: Shouldn't Groovy code be in src/main/groovy?

Comment: It happens because you haven't configured Groovy compilation. You need to add a Maven plugin for this. Check the Groovy homepage or search the web for "maven groovy".

Comment: just moved the groovy class to src/main/groovy (no other changes) and still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only added groovy as dependency. It is no different from adding any other jar, like spring.jar.

You need to add groovy compiler as maven plugin to your project so that groovy compiler will compile groovy classes for you.

See example below, taken [from mailing list.](http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td5709858i10|a5710494)

```
<properties>
  <gmavenVersion>1.4</gmavenVersion>
  <gmavenProviderSelection>2.0</gmavenProviderSelection>
  <groovyVersion>2.0.0</groovyVersion>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>${groovyVersion}</version>
  dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gmavenVersion}</version>
        <configuration>
          <providerSelection>${gmavenProviderSelection}</providerSelection>
          <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generateStubs</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
           <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
           <version>${groovyVersion}</version>
         </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: this link is broken :(

Comment: @M-T-A Changed to different link and also added code example.